# Does selenium sulfate corrode or otherwise react with metals?

Tags: applied-chemistry, chemistry-in-fiction

I was just watching a cartoon called Motorcity, and they featured a real compound called selenium sulfate.

While I'm sure that the compound blowing up a detached steel [car part] on contact is just cartoon wackiness, I'm curious whether it actually does anything bad to any metals, especially since a close compound, selenium sulfide, is commonly used in shampoos.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, selenium sulfide is well known and it is used in anti-dandruff shampoo but other sulfur-containing selenium compounds are not really well known. Selenium sulfate, properly selenium(II) sulfate, $\ce{SeSO4}$ is unknown to the best of my knowledge. [The analogous tellurium compound has been synthesized recently,](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/zaac.201400616/abstract) but still it is not a proper sulfate compound, rather it is actually an oxide-sulfate mixture type of compound.

In case you are wondering whether selenium sulfate will be obtained by reacting selenium with sulfuric acid, then you are wrong. [Selenium and sulfuric acid would react to form a mixture of acids (selenous and selenic acid) but they would all disproportionate to selenium dioxide, sulfur dioxide and water.](http://chemiday.com/en/reaction/3-1-0-11635)

$$\ce{Se + 2H2SO4 ->[\Delta] SeO2 + 2SO2 + 2H2O}$$

[Selenium sulfite or properly selenium sulfoxide, $\ce{SeSO3}$, is however known.](http://selenium.atomistry.com/selenium_sulphoxide.html)

So, selenium sulfate is a fictitious compound and thus used in the cartoon.

Comment: Just as an additional detail: "selenium sulfide" is actually *selenium disulfide*, $\ce{S=Se=S}$, and not some salt of $\ce{Se^n+}$ and $\ce{S^2-}$. (**Five years later edit**: this is incorrect, please see below.)

Comment: @orthocresol Selenium (di)sulfide is not even that. Commercial material, as in shampoos, are actually a mixture of various molecules containing selenium and sulfur. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_disulfide.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Hmph, interesting. I don't even know what motivated me to post that comment, then.